# Refresh problem when treeview node changed

Tags: asp.net, treeview, master-pages

I have a Treeview in a masterpage and a products page in child page.

When i click treeview node i want to bind data to a gridview on the product page.

```
protected void trvCategoryTab_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
  if (trvCategoryTab.SelectedNode.Value != string.Empty)
  {            
    Response.Redirect("~/Customer/Products.aspx?Search=" + trvCategoryTab.SelectedNode.Value);
  }
}
```

It's working fine, but the problem is that the page reloads every time. I want to prevent this.

Is there any other method to redirect to the child page?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to use AJAX.